# Убрать пробелы

Tags: html, javascript

Мне надо убрать пробелы типо <br />

Вот код html из-за которых кстати если вставить 2 в строчку, то делается пробел:

```
           <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="spoiler_links"><img src="images/games/tankionline.jpg" class="games-images"></a>
    <div class="spoiler_body">
  Под спойлером
      </div>
      </div>
```

js скрипт для работы спойлера:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.spoiler_links').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().children('div.spoiler_body').toggle('normal');
  return false;
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: где у вас тут `пробелы типо <br />` ? `$('br').remove();` не подойдет ?

Comment: Единственная догадка: топик-стартеру нужно убрать отступ после картинки.  

    .games-images {display: block;}

Comment: Все равно все идет в столбик http://prntscr.com/2r7jn4

Comment: @eicto все спойллеры становятся не в ряд, а в столбик.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по комментариям ТС, ему нужно, чтобы все блоки располагались в одну строчку.
**Решение:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
         var spoiler_links = $(".spoiler_links");

         spoiler_links.parent().css('display', 'inline-block');
         spoiler_links.click(function(){
             $(this).parent().children('div.spoiler_body').toggle('normal');
             return false;
         });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: А куда это надо вставить или вообще заменить?

Comment: Щас почти нормально. Я просто добавил этот скрипт в js со спойлером, но вот какая щас проблема: 
До нажатия - http://prntscr.com/2r7ryg

При нажатии (нормально) - http://prntscr.com/2r7sb6
А мне надо, чтоб сразу все стояло в строчку.

Comment: Дайте ссылку на сайт. Скорее всего, перекрываются стили.

Comment: Кстати, вот вы щас поменяли ответ и стало работать. Спасибо